# How to add drill down to an SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report where I am getting all records for a certain transaction which has a date counts in which that event has occurred.

How does the drill down work? What is the way when I click on the counts of dates it will drill through to all those corresponding transactions with those dates.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to adding a "drill down" in an SSRS report. You have `Drilldown Reports`, `Nested Data Regions`, `Subreport`, and `Drillthrough Reports`. I highly recommend you check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/drillthrough-drilldown-subreports-and-nested-data-regions?view=sql-server-ver15) to get an idea of how each of them work. Then you can decide which method best meets your needs. Below are a couple links with more user friendly tips.

[Drill Down Techniques in SSRS with the Visibility Property](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1329/drill-down-techniques-in-ssrs-with-the-visibility-property/)

[SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 Drilldown Features](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2831/sql-server-reporting-services-2012-drilldown-features/)